# Search to DataGridView ( showing record) selected record print vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, visual-studio-code, search, crystal-reports

This is my code but it prints all records. I want to search a record and print crystalreport.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        '
        Me.Patient_tblTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DoctorDataSet.patient_tbl)

    End Sub

 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        PatienttblBindingSource.Filter = "(Convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '" & TextBox1.Text & "%')"
    End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1
        rpt.SetDataSource(DoctorDataSet)
        Form2.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt

        Form2.ShowDialog()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you put in an exact value for the filter and use `=` instead of `LIKE`, does it show just one record?

Comment: yes , put a vallue on text1

Comment: @AndrewMorton sir I want to contact u by Mail.. my mail: bishapbm@gmail.com ....  I need to support you.

Answer (score 0):

try to use '*' instead '%' in like statement :

PatienttblBindingSource.Filter = "(Convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '" & TextBox1.Text & "*')"